# MIB not "refreshed"

Tags: snmp, mib

I want to change my MIB structure (custom MIB already working).
I have run ./configure.
I have changed customMIB.txt and rewrite snmpd.conf.
SNMPD services are restarted.

MIB changes : entry2 INTEGER -> OCTET STRING.
But I have theses results :

```
# snmpwalk -Of -cxyz -v 2c localhost customMIB:entry
.iso.org.dod.[...].entry.entry1 = INTEGER: 1
.iso.org.dod.[...].entry.entry2 = Wrong Type (should be OCTET STRING): INTEGER: 0
```

It seems to be a problem of refrehing the MIB ...

It's surely stupid issue but I am researching on the Internet for many hours and I don't find solution.

System information :
- Linux RedHat 6.3
- net-snmp 5.5

I wish to thank you in advance for helping me.

PS : forgive my poor english.

---

Solution :
My fault, I use *netsnmp_register_long_instance* instead of *netsnmp_register_watched_instance* in my subagent.
=> INTEGER instead of OCTET STRING.
It was not a refresh problem but difference between MIB description and MIB subagent.

Please accept my apologies.

Problem resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, I use netsnmp_register_long_instance instead of netsnmp_register_watched_instance in my subagent. => INTEGER instead of OCTET STRING. It was not a refresh problem but difference between MIB description and MIB subagent.

Please accept my apologies.